# how to get a list of all content type groups using sharepoint client model in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a windows application that will allow user with an interface to create custom content-types. Everything is done except I want a dropdown list that will show all available content-types, just like the Sharepoint has.
[image]

What I've achieved so far is:

```
var contentTypes = context.Web.AvailableContentTypes.Where(q => q.Group == "List content type");
```

What exactly I want is a dropdown where all the content-type groups are listed just like the way the above image has.

Please suggest a way to get this done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("URL");

SP.Web web = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(web, w => w.AvailableContentTypes);

var cts = ctx.Web.AvailableContentTypes;

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var groups = cts.ToList().Select(ct => ct.Group).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks @ssoungnez. One question, does it list all the groups like Document, List, etc. ?

Comment: It gets all the content types and retrieve their groups, so normally, you'll get the groups of all available content types, including Document.

Comment: I just modified the code I gave you. When I tested it, I noticed that "Select" was not supported by COM.

Comment: what type of collection would it be?

Comment: An Enumerable<DistrinctIterator> but you can use it like any other collection.

Comment: Hi, there's one more thing I'd like to ask. groups variable now shows the groups of the content-types. What do I do to retrieve the content-types from these groups and their corresponding IDs.

Comment: The thing is that you already have all content types, so if you cast the result with the "ToList" method, you can do whatever you want.

For example, with this code as a base:

`ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("URL");

SP.Web web = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(web, w => w.AvailableContentTypes);

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var cts = ctx.Web.AvailableContentTypes.ToList();`

You can get all groups:

`var groups = cts.ToList().Select(ct => ct.Group).Distinct();`

Or you can get all content types of a group:

`var ctOfGroup = cts.Where(c => c.Group == "Group");`